# Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH? on mac

Tags: python-3.x, poppler

Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

poppler installed...reinstalled
pdf2image installed....reinstalled

note:
Having Python version 3 and 2
using 3...as python -V
code running on 3

## -----python code

from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('dhl.pdf', 500)

Location is also correct.

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 186, in _page_count
    raise PDFInfoNotInstalledError('Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?')

PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. 
pdf2image has the Poppler dependency.

What you need to do is the following.

```
 brew install poppler
```

in your mac terminal.

Answer (score 0):

After `brew install poppler` you can try this :

```
pdf = convert_from_path('path/to/pdf')

len(pdf) # this gives the count to the number of pages in pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by replacing the *poppler_path*

**from**

```
poppler_path= '\usr\bin'
```

**to**

```
poppler_path= '\usr\local\bin'
```

or try to print all the places that poppler might be  in your mac
by `echo $PATH` in the Terminal, and try all the options as `poppler_path =` .